# Where is stored namespaced class?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I have PHP namespaced file

```
namespace A\B\C
$cls = new foo();
```

Where is the **foo** class stored?

OR if exist **__autoload()** how to control directory mapping to namespace?

Thanks for helping. Im trying to closer understand relation between directories and namespaces. PHP and/or Google doesnt give me any answer.

Comment: Have a read of [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Comment: Thanks for link Mark. PSR this is nice activity.

Answer (score 1):

There is not direct relation between directories and namespaces, except if you use an autoloader.

If you want this code to works :

```
namespace A\B\C;
$cls = new foo();
```

*You must do this :*

```
namespace A\B\C;
class foo {}
$cls = new foo();
```

*Or do this :*

**foo.php**

```
namespace \A\B\C;

class foo {}
```

**index.php**

```
require 'foo.php';

$cls = new \A\B\C\foo();
// or
namespace A\B\C;
$cls = new foo();
```

Now if you want to use autoloader, you can use something like this :

```
function autoload($class)
{
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);

    require_once __DIR__ . '/' . $class . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Put this kind of code in top of your index.php and the get a dir arch like this :

```
A
+ B
| + C
| | + foo.php
```

Then you just have to do :

```
$cls = new \A\B\C\foo();
```

or even :

```
use \A\B\C\foo;
$cls = new foo();
```

But anyway, YOU MUST READ MANUAL : [Link here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: Thanks Bob0t. I have already red manual, but I cannot catch the core. Your answer clarify this. As I understood. The PHP build the "full namespace name" from NS declaration and name of class. This full name is something like `\A\B\C\foo` where foo is the class name. So - when I want to load the file where the class is stored - I MUST translate this full name into the right file location eg. with autoload. So there has to be a **strong relation between NS path and file path**. Right? Now when I want to implement other libraries I have to understand how is the NS path mapped into files. Right?

Comment: Yep, in fact, if you use NS, its basically to sort your classes in files, for example i always use the same `Core` library, so its NS is `\Core`, and all the classes are into the directory `ROOT . 'Core/'` you see ? Into that core i have some database related classes, they are into `Core/Database` so the namespace used is `\Core\Database`. I don't know if i'm really clear on this :/ there are good video tutorials you should find on web :)